# Let a, b, c, d, e be a five - term geometric sequence {GP} where a, b, c, d, e are integers and 0 < a < b < c < d <e < 100 .

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let a, b, c, d, e be a five - term geometric sequence {GP} where a, b, c, d, e are integers and 0 < a < b < c < d <e < 100 .We have to find the sum of all possible values of c,

What I have done is  taking the GP ratio as $ \alpha $ and
 $$ \alpha = b/a $$ but we are not confirm that $b/a$ is in simplest form , considering the simplest form of $ b/a $ = $n/m$  and n,m $ \in  \mathbb{Z} $ and the GCD of $n$ and $m$ is 1.  and as GP is in increasing order, the value of $\alpha > 1$ hence, $ n>m$,

anyone who can continue from here , or anyone has any other approach to solve this question

Comment: @user10354138 I am confused by your comment.  I know that $\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^4$ must be $\leq 100$, but I don't see how that immediately implies that you must have $n < 5$.

Comment: Note that $(a,b,c,d,e)$ must be $(km^4,km^3n,km^2n^2,kmn^3,kn^4)$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.  So that means $n^4\leq kn^4=e<100$ and hence $1\leq m<n<4$, which is not a lot of possibilities for $m,n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha=\frac nm$ with $\gcd(n,m)=1$, then $e=\frac{an^4}{m^4}$ being an integer implies that $m^4\mid a$. Similarly, $a=\frac{em^4}{n^4}$, so $n^4\mid e$. Since both $a$ and $e$ are below $100$, this severely limits what $m$ and $n$ can be. Try every possibility.